# Laravel 9 use base_path() in .env file variable

Tags: environment-variables, laravel-9

There is a special string pattern to use base_path() into .env file variable ?

Something like : `MY_PATH=%basePath%/my/path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any external environment variables in the .env.

For example, you could set BASE_PATH in a shell call:

```
BASE_PATH=/Users/home php artisan my:command
```

Then you simply use them in the .env e.g.

```
MY_FILE="${BASE_PATH}/files/something.txt"
```

I think you can also assign environment variables in your web server.